# Is there any way Visio 2013 can be used in my web page

Tags: visio

Now Vision is available in cloud and provides APIs.  I have a requirement where the visio should be used inside a webpage and then the data has to be saved to the visio cloud. I should be able to edit the visio online and save to visio cloud the edited file.  Is the visio APIs support online. Is there any help documents available?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding the situation, i.e. what is actually meant under "Visio is available in the cloud".

One thing is, Visio is now available by subscription (Office 365); but for Visio this merely means that you can use desktop Visio and pay for usage monthly for example.

Another thing is, you can use SharePoint Visio Services (incl. SharePoint online) which have a lot of nice features, like rendering of Visio files for the web, using linked live data sources to update shape graphics on rendering. These Visio services provide you also with API (most probably this is the one you've heard about) which you could use to interact with the rendered drawing client-side. BUT. First, these Visio services are part of SharePoint (Enterprise edition), which means, you can't use them outside of the SharePoint. And second, they still do not allow you to modify/save diagrams, only to render them.

Means, currently (as of Visio 2013) there is no support from Microsoft for editing Visio drawings in web; there is no Visio "Web App" (like Word/Excel Web App). If you need such an app, I'm afraid you'll have to write one yourself.